# Ansible failed_when condition not preventing task from failing

Tags: ansible

I am running the following `ansible` task:

```
    - name: Remove Jenkins
      register: jenkins_delete
      shell: "helm delete --purge --tls jenkins-{{ env_name }}"
      retries: 2
      delay: 20
      until: jenkins_delete.rc == 0
      failed_when: "'jenkins-{{ env_name }} not found' not in jenkins_delete.stderr"
```

If the release I am looking for does not exist, fails as follows:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 5, "changed": true, "cmd": "helm delete --purge --tls jenkins-inception", "delta": "0:00:00.212773", "end": "2020-01-24 13:58:24.993134", "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-01-24 13:58:24.780361", "stderr": "Error: release: \"jenkins-inception\" not found", "stderr_lines": ["Error: release: \"jenkins-inception\" not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Shouldn't the `failed_when` condition I am using be preventing this?

**edit**: I have also tried this one without any success:

```
    - name: Remove Jenkins
      register: jenkins_delete
      shell: "helm delete --purge --tls jenkins-{{ env_name }}"
      retries: 2
      delay: 10
      until: jenkins_delete.rc == 0 or jenkins_delete.stderr is regex("release:.+not found")
```

which is weird given that it seems that the `regex` used should [match](https://regex101.com/r/3VNeoB/2) the string in `stderr`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, there are quotes around `jenkins-inception` in your `stderr`:

`"Error: release: \"jenkins-inception\" not found"`.

This regex should match:

`"jenkins-{{ env_name }}" not found`